# Web Scraping in Asp.net? Any library?

Tags: asp.net, web-scraping, web-crawler

I have used HTML Agility pack but it does not allow me to crawl pages and also i found watin but its website not working yet. Can any body suggest me with list of libraries?

I have to fill some information than click button and then extract some information from responded pages.

Comment: Why are you writing a web application to scrape the web?

Comment: I need to collect some data from various sites but that if some user requests that info because user/ has to enter some customer id on the basis of which i will him info getting it from some other site.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this open source web crawler; http://code.google.com/p/abot/

Comment: As i am not expert in web requests etc i wanted something simple like mechanize in python with good documentation.